# .on('click', function () { во всплывающем окне

Tags: jquery

По клику на кнопку открывается всплывающее окно

```
$('.modal-js').on('click', function () {...}
```

В этом окне есть инпут с классом "cart_auth_username", события в котором мне надо отлавливать. Строка

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.cart_auth_username', function () {
console.log(123)
}
```

работает не корректно, что проявляется в том, что событие срабатывает не в момент изменения инпута, а момент клика мышкой на любом месте. Причём в консоль после этого выводятся 2 строчки

```
123
123
```

Строка `$(document).on('change', 'input.cart_aut....` не вложена `$('.modal-js').on('click', function () {сюда}`, а расположена отдельно.

В чём причина ошибки?

---

```
//модалка
$('.modal-js').on('click', function () {
    var provider_id = $('.mj').data('provider_id');
    //обновляем от предыдущего закрытия
    $('#step2_' + provider_id).css({'display': 'block'});
    if (CatalogComponent.clientName == '') {
        clear23(provider_id);
        hide23(provider_id);
    }
    var recid = $(this).data('user_id');
    var el = $('#rec' + recid);
    var popup = el.find('.t-popup');
    var valmod = el.find('.valmod');

    popup.css({'display': 'flex', 'justify-content': 'center', 'align-items': 'center', 'cursor': 'default'});
    valmod.css({'background-color': 'rgba(255,255,255,1)', 'width': '100%', 'height': '98%', 'overflow-y': 'auto', 'overflow-x': 'hidden'});
    setTimeout(function () {
        popup.find('.t-popup__container').addClass('t-popup__container-animated');
        popup.addClass('t-popup_show');
    }, 50);

    unblock1();
    $('body').addClass('t-body_popupshowed');

    el.find('.t-popup').mousedown(function (e) {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var maxScrollBarWidth = 17;
        var windowWithoutScrollBar = windowWidth - maxScrollBarWidth;
        if (e.clientX > windowWithoutScrollBar) {
            return;
        }
        if (e.target == this) {
            t778_closePopup();
        }
    });

    el.find('.t-popup__close, .t778__close-text').click(function (e) {
        t778_closePopup();
    });

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            t778_closePopup();
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('change', 'input.cart_auth_username', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var user_id = $(this).data('user_id');
    var max = 17;
    var press = $(this).val().replace(/_/gi, '').length;
    var step, answer;
    var text = 'этот номер не зарегистрирован в базе. Оформить заказ на этот номер?';
    console.log(max);
//    console.log(press);
    if (max == press) {
        var phone = $(this).val();
        CatalogComponent.clientPhone = phone;
        clear123(user_id);
        $.ajax({
           ..........
        });
    }

});
```

html

```
<div id="cart_info_<?=$prov->provider_id?>" class="t812__col t-col t-col_4" style = "width:100%; color: #f7cd00;">
    <div class="t812__pricelist-item_box">
        <div class="t812__pricelist-item__row_1 t-row" style="flex-wrap:wrap; padding-bottom: 0px;">
            <div class="t812__pricelist-item__title t-name t-name_sm" style="text-transform:uppercase; color: #f7cd00; width: 100%;">
                    ...
                    <div id="order_true_<?=$prov->provider_id?>" style="display: <?=$display2?>">
                    <div class="button_order_checkout modal-js" data-user_id ="<?=$prov->provider_id?>" style="margin: 30px auto; width: 150px;">
                        <span style="text-align: center; font-size: 0.7em; color: #f7cd00;">Оформить заказ</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="t812__pricelist-item__line" style="height: 0.4px; background-color: #F7Cd00; opacity: 0.6; margin:0 0 15px 0;"></div>
        <!--модалка-->
        <div id="rec<?=$prov->provider_id?>" data-provider_id="<?=$prov->provider_id?>" class="r t-rec mj scrolbar" data-record-type="754" >
            <div class="t-popup" >
                <div class="valmod">
                    <div class="t-popup__close my_popup__close">x</div>
                    <!--t547-->
                    <div class="t547">
                        <div class="t-section__container t-container">
                            <div class="t-col t-col_12">
                                <div class="t-section__topwrapper t-align_center">
                                    <div class="t-section__title t-title t-title_xs" field="btitle">Оформление заказа на <?=$prov->name_company?></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="t-container t547__container" style="margin-bottom:150px;">
                            <div class="t547__item" id="step1">
                                <div class="t-width t-width_12 t547__mainblock">
                                    <div class="t547__col">
                                        <div class="t547__block">
                                            <div class="t547__title t-name t-name_lg">Идентификация</div>
                                            <div class="t547__descr t-text t-text_xs">
                                                <?php 
                                                if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
                                                    echo 'Введите ваш телефон или авторизируйтесь';
                                                    echo yii\widgets\MaskedInput::widget([
                                                        'name' => 'phone',
                                                        'mask' => '+380(99)-999-9999',
                                                        'options' => [
                                                            'class' => 'cart_auth_username form-control',
                                                            'data-user_id' => $prov->provider_id,
                                                            'placeholder' => 'введите номер телефона'
                                                        ],
                                                    ]);
                                                echo Html::tag('div',null, ['style' => ['display' => 'none', 'margin'=>'15px 0 0 2px'], 'id' => 'caur_'.$prov->provider_id, 'class' => 'caur']);
                                                echo Html::tag('div',
                                                    Html::tag('span','Укажите ФИО полностью. Эти данные используются при оформлении отгрузок на службе доставки.', ['class' => 'migo'])
                                                    .$inputs['fam']
                                                    .$inputs['name']
                                                    .$inputs['otch']
                                                    .Html::tag('div',null,['style' => ['display' => 'none', 'margin'=>'15px 0 15px 2px'], 'id' => 'step_1_finish_'.$prov->provider_id])
                                                    .Html::tag('span','далее→', ['style' => ['pointer-events' => 'none', 'opacity' => '0', 'display' => 'table-cell', 'padding' => '10px !important'], 'data-answ' => 'next', 'id' => 'step_1_next_'.$prov->provider_id, 'class' => 'button_order_checkout boc-js']),
                                                ['style' => ['display' => 'none', 'margin'=>'15px 0 0 2px'], 'id' => 'caur2_'.$prov->provider_id, 'class' => 'caur']);
                                                
                                                } else {
                                                    $user_photo = Yii::$app->user->identity->photo ? '<img src="'.Yii::getAlias('@img/users/'.Yii::$app->user->identity->photo).'" title = "'.Yii::t('app','photo').' '.Yii::$app->user->identity->username.'" alt="'.Yii::$app->user->identity->username.'" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border: thin solid #f7cd00; border-radius: 3px; margin: 0 5px 0 0; vertical-align: text-top; box-shadow: 0 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);">' : null;
                                                    echo '
                                                        <div id="step_1_finish_"'.$prov->provider_id.' style="margin: 15px 0px 0px 2px; opacity: 1;">
                                                                заказ будет оформлен на <br>'.$user_photo.'
                                                                <strong>'.Yii::$app->user->identity->username.'</strong><br>
                                                                <strong>'.Yii::$app->user->identity->phone.'</strong>
                                                        </div>';
                                                    $display_step2 = 'display:block;';
                                                    
                                                    ?>
                                                        <script>
                                                        $(document).ready(function(){
                                                        $('#step2_'+<?=$prov->provider_id?>).animate({"height" : "show"}, 500);    
                                                        CatalogComponent.client_id    =   '<?=Yii::$app->user->identity->id?>';
                                                        CatalogComponent.clientPhone  =   '<?=Yii::$app->user->identity->phone?>';
                                                        CatalogComponent.clientName   =   '<?=Yii::$app->user->identity->username?>';
                                                        CatalogComponent.sellerPhone  =   '<?=Yii::$app->user->identity->phone_who_invited?>';
                                                        });
                                                        </script>
                                                <?php                                  
                                                }

                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="t547__line" style="background-color:#e0e0e0;">
                                        <div class="t547__circle"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            ......
                            .......
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                            
        <!--/модалка-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Comment: да, я забыл упомянуть, что перепробовал разные обработчики событий, но дело не в них. Они все срабатывают после клика на пустом месте.

Comment: попробуйте событие input

Comment: я их все перепробовал) Дело не в них. Добавил код полностью

Comment: можете добавить еще html, css код? И вопрос модальное окно сверстано или создаётся с помощью js?

Comment: готово, выложил

Comment: Я посмотрел ваш код, и немного запутался, вот сверстал на скорую руку простенький пример, это то что вы хотели получить? 
https://codepen.io/Crook/pen/abBwjLR

Comment: да, похоже. Вы делаете функцию клика по элементу внутри модалки вложенной в функцию открытия модалки и не используете $(document).on(...) В чистом виде оно работает и у меня,  тем более, что по коду у меня есть обработка других элементов в модалке и оно нормально работает. Но этот кусок какой-то непонятный. Такое ощущение, что результат где-то сохраняется, а потом выводится от некой активации окна кликом

Comment: да, тоже не сразу понял что вы написали, я думал у вас в модальном окне какая та кнопка, перечитав еще раз, я понял что там текстовое поле, данные которого вы хотите получать, я переделал: https://codepen.io/Crook/pen/JjbJBpx

Comment: вложил функцию в функцию и вроде как завелось! Спасибо!

Comment: Но почему оно выводит в консоль предыдущий результат. Т.е. если ввёл "1" - молчит, ввёл "12" - выводит "1", ввел "123" - выводит "12"

Comment: @Oughtem потому что правильно писать не `keydown`, а `keyup`, а лучше `input`